# How to get nearest players head onto armorstand with summon

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making another map and in this one I need to get the nearest players skull on an armor stand. How would I do that and how would the target selector for putting the nearest players head on an armorstand work?

Comment: Don't think this is possible.

Comment: @colorfusion I know it is I've seen it in other maps.

Comment: Could you link to these maps? Are they using any kind of mods?

Comment: @colorfusion I can't seem to remember which maps but I have played them and I'm using only vanilla Minecraft. I'll see if I can find them.

Comment: I've seen it done on servers, Hypixel, they use vanilla right?

Comment: Hypixel uses a heavily messed up version of spigot. He has a huge team of programmers that make plugins to do this stuff.

Comment: @KingDarren7203 Hypixel is very far from vanilla.

Comment: I just know this can be done in vanilla. I think it might use scoreboard. There just needs to be some kind of @p type selector that you can use for skulls in the command.

Comment: @KingDarren7203 I'm pretty sure this isn't possible in vanilla. If you tell us where you saw this done, it would help greatly with telling you how it was done.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't recall the map I saw it done in. However, a attempted to join a team on scoreboard called 'me'. In the skull owner tag I added [team=me]. Would something like this work?

Comment: Nope, that would not work. Also, it'll take me a while to respond if you don't put @colorfusion, as I won't get notified.

Answer (score 1):

As of Minecraft 1.8 and the upcoming 1.9 (currently snapshot 15w43c), there is no way to do this in vanilla Minecraft, short of a customized command for every single player.

It would require the use of placeholders/variables in NBT data, for which there is just no way.

---

That said, *if* the list of player usernames is known and fixed, you could use one command per player, executing only if that player is the one closest to the execution point.

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ execute @p[name=Alice,r=0] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:"skull",Damage:3,tag:{SkullOwner:"Alice"}}]}
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ execute @p[name=Bob,r=0] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:"skull",Damage:3,tag:{SkullOwner:"Bob"}}]}
...
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ execute @p[name=Zuul,r=0] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:"skull",Damage:3,tag:{SkullOwner:"Zuul"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add player heads onto armour stands by using this command:

/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:"skull",Damage:3,tag:{SkullOwner:"(player name)"}}]}

Comment: This answers how to add the skull to the armour stand, but not how to get the "nearest player's" name/id. Can you add that?

Comment: I need @players or the nearest players head, not a specific head.